# Color-thief.js Color Quality Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm noticing poor color quality on the "dominant color" that's rendered from the color thief js plug-in. I have it working as it should, no issues there.

However, the dominant color is not coming through as it should. It's always a TAD bit lighter or darker. My script is below. The link to the plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief).

Note, on the plug-in site, there's a quality option. But there formatting (i.e. `[, quality]`) is breaking my jQuery code. Not sure what's up with the `[,..`, tried removing and adding it to no avail.

Question - how can I set the quality on the color thief plug-in, which I assume is causing the color rendering issue.

**PS**: To test the dominate color, I'm using an image that's all one color.

```
$('.sb-billboard img.user-img').on('load', function () {
    var getWidth = $(this).width();

    // create img from src
    var image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = '';
    image.src = $(this).attr('src');
    image.width = getWidth;

    // get color
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();

    var userImage = image;
    var dominantColor = colorThief.getColor(userImage);

    $('#campaign-wrap').css("background-color", "rgb(" + dominantColor[0] + "," + dominantColor[1] + "," + dominantColor[2] + ")");
});
```

Comment: Have you tried var dominantColor = colorThief.getColor(userImage, 0); ?  The square brackets are just indicating that the quality parameter is optional.  And 0 is the best quality and 10 is the least (and the default).  Not intuitive :(

Comment: My guess is that trying to programmatically get the dominant color is always going to be a slightly imperfect process. This is the type of thing you hire graphics designers for.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Hmm, I did try that (that was my initial though after I tried a few things, but figured `10` would equal best quality. Never tried `0`. Trying it now and it's really heavy on the CPU...so must be working. Stay tuned.

Comment: @DamienBlack, hope you set higher coding standards for yourself man - perfect is possible! :p Note, I'm an designer and this is for a application - user driven. ;)

Comment: @MikeBarwick The problem is that the 'correct' color to pick is actually a rather complex question that requires years of human expertise. A quick javascript analysis is not going to be able to consistently pick a color up to a designer's standards. Although it should be able to handle an image of one color...

Comment: @BarbaraLaird...setting 0 or 10 in that instance is not for quality. It's for the number of colors to be generated it looks like, etc.